# [Turtlebot] [Kobuki base] Increasing the publish frequency of sensor messages

Tags: turtlebot, kobuki, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I’m using a Turtlebot 2, Kobuki base. I replaced the cliff sensors in order to be able to detect the narrow darker spaces between floor tiles. It works at low speed but, at higher speeds, the transitions are not always detected because the traveled distance between two sensor updates is too long.
Is there a way to increase the frequency of publication of the sensor state message?
Thanks for any input.
Regards.

```
     G. Garcia
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295904/%5Bturtlebot%5D-%5Bkobuki-base%5D-increasing-the-publish-frequency-of-sensor-messages/) by [ggg](https://answers.ros.org/users/15026/ggg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2018-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there, it depends, can you show me what package are you using?

Usually, there are parameters to control frequency like in [this file](https://github.com/yujinrobot/kobuki/blob/643d437f418c33e3b57b86951e36d4f172ab3f9b/kobuki_keyop/param/keyop_smoother.yaml):

```
# Optional parameters
frequency: 20.0
decel_factor: 1.0
```

Try to look for a similar parameter, or if you point the package you are using and I can help you out.

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) with karma: 700 on 2018-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0